# Syntax error on token "(", ; expected

Tags: java, syntax-error

So I'm working in CodingBat, learning Java, but it keeps throwing me this error for the code below.

```
public int noTeenSum(int a, int b, int c) {
    return fixTeen(a)+fixTeen(b)+fixTeen(c);

    public int fixTeen(int x) {
        if(x<=12||x>=20||x==15||x==16)
            return x;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The goal of the problem is as follows:

> Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if any of the values is a teen -- in the range 13..19 inclusive -- then that value counts as 0, except 15 and 16 do not count as a teens. Write a separate helper "public int fixTeen(int n) {"that takes in an int value and returns that value fixed for the teen rule. In this way, you avoid repeating the teen code 3 times (i.e. "decomposition"). Define the helper below and at the same indent level as the main noTeenSum().

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does that error come with a line number?

Comment: It's on the line with public int fixTeen(int x) {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss a `}` after `return fixTeen(a)+fixTeen(b)+fixTeen(c);` and there is no need for last `}`

```
public int noTeenSum(int a, int b, int c) {
 return fixTeen(a)+fixTeen(b)+fixTeen(c);
}

public int fixTeen(int x) {
 if(x<=12||x>=20||x==15||x==16)
  return x;
 return 0;
 }
```